# Is C++ good at reusing the stack memory for local variables?

Tags: c++, optimization, scope, stack, local-variables

Consider the following code:

```
const __m256d a = /* get it in some way */;
const __m256d b = /* get it in some way */;
const __m256d c = /* calculate as a result of operations on a and b */;
const __m256d d = /* get it in some way */;
const __m256d e = /* get it in some way */;
const __m256d f = /* calculate as a result of operations on d and e */;
const __m256d g = /* calculate as a result of operations on c and f */;
```

Here `__m256d` is a long (32-byte) data type consisting of 4 packed `double`'s. It's POD/trivial and built-in (AVX).

So after `c` is calculated, can the compiler dispose `a` and `b` somehow and reuse their memory in the stack for the latter variables (`c`, `d`, etc.)? The same for `d` and `e` after `f` is calculated.

I qualify the variables with `const` to help the compiler optimizing (indicating that there's no need to worry about its value changing). But I could manually manage the stack at expense of dropping some `const`s. Shall I do it?

I'm not considering reusing variable names, because this is too messy. Instead, I would reuse the stack by means of scopes:

```
__m256d g;
{
  __m256d c;
  {
    const __m256d a = /* get it in some way */;
    const __m256d b = /* get it in some way */;
    c = /* calculate as a result of operations on a and b */;
  }
  __m256d f;
  {
    const __m256d d = /* get it in some way */;
    const __m256d e = /* get it in some way */;
    f = /* calculate as a result of operations on d and e */;
  }
  g = /* calculate as a result of operations on c and f */;
}
```

My compiler is MSVC++2017 toolset v141.

Comment: Write the code in a way that makes sense, then look at the disassembly to confirm that the compiler is doing what you want. If it isn't, *then* go in and tweak the code as necessary.

Comment: @CodyGray , that would give a specific answer for that piece of code. But I would like a generic rule to follow. Testing each piece of code seems unproductive.

Comment: There isn't a general rule. Optimization is tricky and imperfect. Especially when intrinsics get involved. And even someone could exhaustively investigate this and determine what *a specific version* of the compiler did in various common circumstances, that wouldn't be very useful because it would be subject to change (and thus need to be re-investigated) when you updated your compiler (much less used one provided by a different vendor).

Comment: Hopefully these all end up in registers anyway.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM uses stack slot coloring to reuse stack slots. GCC does something similar. Since this is isn't a "high-tech" optimization by any means, MSVC *should* have it.